# Cannot resolve method generated by annotation processor

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I have two projects. One of them is `projectA` a processor for annotations. Second one, `projectB` use `projectA` as dependency. Now this processor is add `toJson` method to exists class before final compile. Everything works normally. When I compile `projectB` my `projectA` is run and modify exists source file and add `toJson` method. Also intellij auto detect this processor and automatically configure my custom processor to the processor path. But editor give error `Cannot resolve method 'toJson' in 'CacheData'`. How I can solve this problem?

The below image is my intellij configuration. As you see IDEA automatically detect my processor from my pom.xml but editor does not recognize the generated code
[image: intellij configuration]

I use `IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Ultimate Edition)`, `maven-3.8.1`, `jdk-1.8` for processor(`projectA`) and `jdk-11` for `projectB`

Comment: Does it work if you use the same JDK for both projects?

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC for processor I can not use after jdk8 because of `tools.jar`. But I don't think the problem is because of jdk. because my project compile successfully and when I decode the class method is there. I don't know how lombok plugin works but that is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem. It seems that current version of Intellij only supported auto generated class. But if you modify exist file with you `annotation processor` Intellij editor can not recognize your changes and shows as errors. Thank you very much to @mplushnikov for his [lombok-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin). I just create my own plugin for IntellIJ and add dependence. After doing this you need to override some entrance classes and add your own annotation and its processor handler and extends it from [`AbstractClassProcessor`](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/blob/intellij_master/src/main/java/de/plushnikov/intellij/plugin/processor/clazz/AbstractClassProcessor.java)

Let me share some example so if anyone who has this problem can use it.

[IntellIJ Plugin tutorial](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/welcome.html) for beginner

The below code snippets are from my `plugin.xml`. First you need add some dependencies to your plugin

```
<depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
<depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>
<depends>com.intellij.modules.java</depends>
<depends>Lombook Plugin</depends> <!-- this is the lombok-intellij-plugin-->
```

Second step is adding required extensions to your plugin as below

```
 <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
  <!-- Add your own custom processor. because lombok plugin default search only lombok package and own annotations -->
  <lang.psiAugmentProvider implementation="your_package.AugmentProviderImpl"/>
  <!-- if you packaged your classes other than lombok   -->
  <codeInsight.externalLibraryResolver implementation="your_package.ExternalLibraryImpl"/>
  <implicitUsageProvider implementation="your_package. ImplicitUsageProviderImpl"/>

  <!-- Add your custom annotation processor handler and extend it from   AbstractClassProcessor -->
  <applicationService serviceImplementation="your_package.CustomAnnotationProcessor"/>
 </extensions>
```

Thats it. Follow these steps, build your plugin and install it. After restart your class's methods which is generated by your own annotation will be recognized by intellij.

Implementing the class is not hard. Just look the `lombok-intellij-plugin` source code and copy the required file and just modified it.

Comment: Michail's plugin is a real masterpiece, but my solution was to enhance the plugin itself instead of building new one on top of it. The solution you propose requires specific expertise in JetBrains plugin development which may lead to very much time wasted until a working solution is ready. On the other hand the way of changing existing plugin claims no boilerplate at all and requires just several small changes. Besides, as I can see there are lots of people that forked original Lombok plugin for the same purpose and you may find their (or my own) forks and changes in GitHub to compare efforts.